# php return total with same element in two dimension session array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a cart session with below elements:

**print_r($_SESSION['cart']);**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => X-Dot Motorbike Helmet G88 + Bogo Visor (Test)
            [p_code] => 2102649
            [p_id] => 12332
            [p_price] =>  1.60
            [p_seller] => 230002
            [p_alt-variation-1] => Red
            [p_alt-variation-2] => L - 1.60-36
            [p_qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => Salt and Lemon Candy (20 Packs/Carton)
            [p_code] => 3443268
            [p_id] => 11654
            [p_price] => 1.20
            [p_seller] => 230002
            [p_qty] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => Romoss Rolink Hybrid Premium Cable
            [p_code] => TEST421
            [p_id] => 10670
            [p_price] => 13.90
            [p_seller] => 230001
            [p_qty] => 1
        )

)
```

As seen on the `[p_seller]`, I want to group the same p_seller value and return the number :

> return **2** through the array (230002), and  return **1** through the
>   array (230001)

how can I do that?

Comment: p_seller has `**230001**` value or you trying to bold those numbers ???

Comment: bold only, removed

Comment: *the number* is not *total with same element*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You have to try this code

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        'p_name' => "X-Dot Motorbike Helmet G88 + Bogo Visor (Test)",
        'p_seller' => '230002',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'p_name' => "X-Dot Motorbike Helmet G88 + Bogo Visor (Test)",
        'p_seller' => '230002',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'p_name' => "X-Dot Motorbike Helmet G88 + Bogo Visor (Test)",
        'p_seller' => '230001',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$result = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'p_seller'));
   arsort($result);// not neccesary
   echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [230002] => 2
    [230001] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the array `indexes`will always same, then you can simple sum the values.

Try

```
echo $_SESSION['cart'][1]['p_seller'] + $_SESSION['cart'][2]['p_seller'];
```

**For Dynamically**

You can use `array_sum` with `foreach` loop

Try

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $val)
{
    if( isset($val['p_seller']) )
        $total[] = $val['p_seller'];
}
if( isset($total) && is_array($total) )
{
    $total = array_sum($total);
    echo $total;
}
```

**Update 1**

As I understand you just want to `echo` the values found in INDEX `p_seller`.

Try

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $val)
{
    if( isset($val['p_seller']) )
    {
        echo ++$i.' - '.$val['p_seller']."<br >";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not clear enough, i want to return the number   found with same **ID**, instead of sum up the ID. From the above example, I expect **2** and **1** as the results.

Comment: I try your update answer, get stuck on `$++i`, error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in C:\xampp...`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $Arrvalues){
  $total+= $Arrvalues['p_seller'];
}
echo $total;
```

output : 690005